# How to install Credhub as a service broker on Korifi?

Tags: cloud-foundry, cloudfoundry-uaa, credhub, korifi

I am very new to the Kubernetes space and the Korifi management/ installation also.

Was able to install korifi over a VM (accessible publicly)

**Need some answers relating to credhub.**

How can I make the credhub available as a service broker in case of korifi? I can push the credhub as an app to same korifi org/ space.

**UAA** is already in place, but I need to install credhub also for managing the environment variables, secrets, etc.